# Why does my inputs do not change the value of coords to create a point?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project using react and I'm having some trouble, I want to add some coords by using onChange on a pair of inputs but I'm having some trouble, it says addMarker2 isn't defined but it is(?

```
      const addMarker2 = () => {
      const element = document.createElement('div')
      element.className = 'marker'
      const marker2 = new tt.Marker({
        element: element,
      })
        .setLngLat([longitude2, latitude2])
        .addTo(map)    
    }
    recalculateRoutes() 

<div className="search">
        <input 
          type="text" 
          className="lat"
          id="lat"
          placeholder="Latitud segundo punto"
          onChange = {(e) =>
            {
              setLatitude2(e.target.value)
              if(latitude2 != null && longitude2 != null) {             
                addMarker2()
              }
            }  
          }  
        />
        <input 
          type="text" 
          className="long"
          id="long"
          placeholder="Longitud segundo punto"
          onChange = {(e) =>
            {
              setLongitude2(e.target.value)
              if(latitude2 != null && longitude2 != null) {              
                addMarker2()
                
              }
            }  
          }
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: Please post a complete component that demonstrates the problem. There is not enough information here to know where the problem is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.